# How to send the MFRC522 RFID module into sleep mode?

Tags: arduino-uno, power, rfid, sleep

I'm trying to get the power consumption of a MFRC522 RFID module down, currently while running it consumes about 4mA. There should be a way to put it into sleep mode, I just can't find any documentation on it. I'm using the module with a arduino currently if that helps; and this is the module itself : [MFRC522](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00E0ODLWQ)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MFRC522.pdf

Look at section `8.6.2   Soft power-down mode`.

Comment: I still don't get how to implement this in my arduino code.

Comment: First, that wasn't your question. Secondly, you didn't say how you connected it. Are you using SPI or UART? What library are you using?

Comment: I didn't know there was anything other than an SPI library for it; but currently using SPI.

Comment: Two questions, one answer. I'm done helping you.

Comment: Sam, it sounds like you're asking two different questions: "How do I put the MFRC522 into sleep mode?" and "How do I send commands, such as the soft power-down command, from an Arduino to the MFRC522?". I suggest you open a separate, independent question to ask that second question, as recommended by http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts .